# Несвойственно или не свойственно

Tags: частица-не

Слитно или раздельно следует писать "не"
Молодости несвойственно отчаиваться.

Answer (score 3):

В этом случае лучше применить слитную форму написания: "Молодости несвойственно отчаиваться". Это безличное предложение, где предикативное наречие входит в состав составного глагольного сказуемого.

В принципе возможны обе формы написания, но писать раздельно не имеет смысла. По содержанию две формы не различаются, можно только выделить отрицание логическим ударением. Но для этого желательно перестроить предложение, например: "Не свойственно  молодости отчаиваться в таких случаях".

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, конечно, надо писать слитно.Если уже написано раздельно, а видимых причин нет, тогда такое написание объясняют отрицанием.Самое сложное - это определить отрицание.

Comment: Думаю, что отрицание не надо объяснять, с трудом определять и искать там, где его нет. Отрицательный смысл чаще всего заложен в самой структуре предложения, его надо просто "считать", в том числе с устного варианта предложения. В нашем случае мы можем написать НЕ раздельно и утверждать, что это отрицание, но в устной речи оно никак не прочитывается.

Comment: Да, я письменную речь и имела в виду.